JsonApiDotNetCore - How to filter by related object property?
Imagine I have two objects
public class OrderLine : Identifiable<Guid>
{
   [HasOne]
   public Order Order {get;set;}
   ...
   // other properties
}

public class Order : Identifiable<Guid>
{
   [Attr]
   public Guid CompanyId { get; set;}

   [HasMany]
   public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines {get; set;}
   ...
   // other properties
}


I want to perform an implicit filtering (independent of the filter created by the frontend). I want to filter the OrderLines by the CompanyId which is not directly on the object but is on the related parent object.
So I am implementing the OnApplyFilter(string existing filter), where I need the AttrAttribute to create an expression, etc. (as described on the JsonApiDotnetCore web page).
public override FilterExpression? OnApplyFilter(FilterExpression? existingFilter)
{
    // some initialization and Db fetching
    
    AttrAttribute companyIdAttribute = ResourceType.Attributes
            .Single(account => account.Property.Name == "Order.CompanyId"); 
            //This does not work and I am wondering what to do...
    // ...
    // some logic
    
    var exp = new ComparisonExpression(
           ComparisonOperator.Equals, 
           new ResourceFieldChainExpression(companyIdAttribute), 
           new LiteralConstantExpression("some company id which signed user has access to"))

    // rest of the method checking the filter and returning the appended `existingFilter` by my
    // custom filter
}



The attr lookup doesn't work because CompanyId has no [Attr] on it. But more importantly, what you're trying to do seems to be implementing multi-tenancy. There's a fully working implementation at https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/blob/master/test/JsonApiDotNetCoreTests/IntegrationTests/MultiTenancy/MultiTenancyTests.cs. In that sample, country codes are used to distinguish web shops, similar to the companyID you're using. The sample is built in such a way that tenants are always separated, which applies to both read and write endpoints. At its core, it uses an EF Core query filter (see the DbContext class).

Yeah my bad, I have the [Attr] on these fields (I will edit the question). However, after I went through the sample, I don't know how that solves my problem. I did not find a method, which would test "from code" filtering by related object properties. Everything is testing the filtering using the URL queries, which works fine for me. I am not sure how to implement this filter in code in OnApplyFilter() block.  I know "Order.CompanyId" is wrong as there is no such property on the OrderLine. I need to filter the OrderLines by the ComapnyId every time and eventually add the existing URL filter

Doing this from OnApplyFilter isn't reliable because it isn't being applied in all cases. For example, a GET request to /orders/1/lines potentially shows order lines from a company that the logged-in user shouldn't have access to because it belongs to a different company. The reason is because OnApplyFilter is called for OrderLine, but not for Order.
The only reliable way is via EF Core HasQueryFilter. The sample uses an URL path segment to indicate the tenant only for simplicity; that data typically comes from an auth token (see comments on ITenantProvider).

Yeah, I am aware of that. I encountered the exact situation you mentioned, so I turned off the relationship Reading methods for certain users (so they won't accidentally get to data the should not see). Thank you for your information, I will try to implement it in the future. I will mark you answer as accepted.
